# Facebook Login return result code 0 first time, when we click again then login successfully, why first time retun 0 in android sdk?

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on facebook login with some permission, that getting some problem when we click on login button that time onAvtivity result return 0, when we click again that time return success, why this problem generate.

My code is given as under......

```
    private LoginButton fbLoginButton;
    fbLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fbLoginButton);
    fbLoginButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    fbLoginButton.registerCallback(mFacebookCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Utility.storeString(mPreferences, PrefrennceList.FB_ACCESSTOKEN, loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            Utility.storeString(mPreferences, PrefrennceList.FB_USER_ID, loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(SocialLoginActivity.this, PrefrennceList.FB_READ_PERMISSION);
            Logger.e(TAG,"Decline Pemisssion List : "+AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getDeclinedPermissions());
            Logger.e(TAG, "Facebook Token is :" + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            Logger.e(TAG, "Facebook User Id is :" + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());
            SauthUserCallAPI(mPreferences.getString(PrefrennceList.UID, ""), Snetwork, loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken(), token_secret, mPreferences.getString(PrefrennceList.COMPANY_ACCESS_TOKEN, ""));
            return;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });


 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Logger.e(TAG, "Result code Request :" + requestCode);

        Logger.e(TAG, "Result code Fb :" + resultCode);
        mFacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     }
}
```

Comment: have you resolved this? As I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use : **compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0'**

```
login_buttonFb.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Logger.e(TAG, "Result AccessToken is: " + loginResult.getAccessToken());
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            getFacebookUserInformation(accessToken);
            Logger.e(TAG, "Result is: " + accessToken.getToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Logger.e(TAG,"Erorro Facebook : "+ error);
            AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));

        }
    });
```

may be solved using this.